# Why log4j2 not rolling over after reaching the max and keeps overwriting the default log file?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am using the below configuration to generate the log rolling based on size. The logs are created, however the rolling stops after creating the max files (10). The default file is keep on overwriting and all the rolled over files never gets updated.

```
appender.sample.type = RollingFile
appender.sample.name = SampleRollingFile
appender.sample.fileName = ${basedir}/logs/${machine}_My_Sample.0.log
appender.sample.filePattern = ${basedir}/logs/${machine}_My_Sample.%i.log
appender.sample.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.sample.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [T:%T] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.sample.policies.type = Policies
appender.sample.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.sample.policies.size.size = 100MB
appender.sample.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.sample.strategy.max = 10
```

But when I changed my default initial file name to My_Sample.log (removing the .0 index) it works perfectly fine. My application requirement is initial file with .0 and the rolling the logs from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

I added the below properties to get the desired result. By enabling tracing (status = TRACE) in the log4j2 they use the index 0 to play around with the renaming and purge. To avoid the collision, I started the index from 1 and the continuous rolling is happening !!

```
appender.sample.strategy.fileIndex = 1
appender.sample.strategy.min = 1
```